# Possible to put the (secondary) axis next to the plot (instead of the facet label)

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using facets and an axis on the same side of plot the facet label comes before the axis. While it makes sense for labels with dark background, it looks strange for white background labels. Here an MWE example:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat)) +
  facet_grid(cut~.) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Plot:

[image]

Is it possible to swap the facet labels and the secondary axis, so that the axis is next to the plot?

Mockup:
[image]

Comment: For clarity, I do not care whether the axis label ("count" in the example) is next to the axis ticks or next to facet label (like in the mockup).

Comment: The code does not correspond to the images. It is for boxplot and you are showing histograms.

Comment: @MabelVillalba thanks for noticing. copy pasted the wrong snippet. I've updated the code. sry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
require(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat))  +
  geom_histogram() + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        plot.margin=margin(c(.1,.1,.1,.1),unit="pt"))+
  facet_grid(cut~.)
```

[image]

Comment: `strip.placement = "outside"` does the trick, thanks. hard to find if one does not know what to search the help for :)

Comment: It's ok! Glad I could help.